# Magento 2 Admin sales/order_create/index/ - there is header and footer loading

Tags: checkout, sales-order, magento2.3.0

**Developer,**

Magento 2.3
Click Create New Order then redirect to **sales/order_create/index**/ - there are header and footer loading

> Looking for the help

Comment: while loading the page... only content is loading... header and footer is missing on that page

Comment: @trusha - any idea?

Comment: Check your error log at var/log folder. you might get a clue for there

Comment: @AmitBera - main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://example.com/admin/sales/order_create/index/key/b0fa5663426f7968f885b87879991f07c3cd253690cc25e641aae26cab891b3b/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_SYSTEM_CONFIG"}} []

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing cache.

```
Clean Cache:

php bin/magento cache:clean
Flush Cache:

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

(optional) if clearing cache doesn't seem to show any changes, you might need to do a static deploy.

Static Deploy: Note: this will take a bit of time depending on your system.

```
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

After these processes you can try and reload the page again.

If clearing cache does not help then may be you have added script in a wrong way inside inside the file default_head_blocks.xml.